# What was the letter written by Charlie before he died in Lost?

Tags: lost

[Charlie Pace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Pace) is a fictional character on ABC's Lost, a television series chronicling the lives of plane crash survivors on a mysterious tropical island. Played by Dominic Monaghan.

In the season three finale "Through the Looking Glass", Charlie drowns at the hands of Mikhail Bakunin (Andrew Divoff), sacrificing himself in an effort to save the other survivors.

I could recall that he was in love with Claire, a very pretty lady who was pregnant when the plane crashes.

I also remember that we wrote a very touching letter or bullet points for someone (probably Claire) before he died. About five or six things that happened to him. For example:

1. You taught me how to swim.
2. Etc...

It was very touching, and I could not remember it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Claire was not pregnant with Charlie's baby, though he treated the child as if it were his own. In [S01E10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_by_Another), it is shown that the father of her child is her ex-boyfriend [Thomas](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas).

I believe you're looking for [Charlie's Greatest Hits](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Charlie's_list), which was a list of his Top 5 memories.  That list was supposed to be delivered to Claire in the event he didn't make it back.

- #5 - The First Time I Heard Myself On the Radio
- #4 - Dad Teaching    Me To Swim at Butlins
- #3 - The Christmas Liam Gave Me the Ring
- #2 - Woman Outside Covent Garden Calls Me a Hero
- #1 - The Night I Met You